# default font for spacemacs only changes inside terminal

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

I have tried the following things:

1. including the following in my .spacemacs

```
dotspacemacs-default-font '("Fira Code" 
:size 16 
:weight normal  
:width normal  
:powerline-scale 1.1)
```

2. Doing options, set default font, save options

neither of which has actually updated my font settings. When I restart spacemacs, the font is back to the default 12pt Source Code Pro. However, when I run spacemacs -nw so that spacemacs runs inside my terminal, my font settings ARE preserved. What am I doing wrong?

My emacs version is 26.3.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hack found [here:](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/3477)
If I add

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :family "Fira Code")
 (set-face-attribute 'default nil :height 160)
```

to my .spacemacs above the automatically generated code for setting the font, it works.